# Python find list lengths in a sublist

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find out how to get the length of every list that is held within a particular list. For example:

```
a = []
a.append([])
a[0].append([1,2,3,4,5])
a[0].append([1,2,3,4])
a[0].append([1,2,3])
```

I'd like to run a command like:

```
len(a[0][:])
```

which would output the answer I want which is a list of the lengths [5,4,3]. That command obviously does not work, and neither do a few others that I've tried. Please help!

Comment: Is it possible that a list inside a[0] also contains lists?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`[len(x) for x in a[0]]` ?

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append([])
>>> a[0].append([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a[0].append([1,2,3,4])
>>> a[0].append([1,2,3])
>>> [len(x) for x in a[0]]
[5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Depending on the size of your a[0] you may want to opt for Matthew Iselin's solution using map.  In some cases (where lambda is not needed) map may be marginally faster.  But that would only be for a very large a[0]

Answer (score 10):

`map(len, a[0])`

Answer (score 3):

```
[len(x) for x in a[0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is known as [List comprehension](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/mapping_lists.html) (click for more info and a description).

```
[len(l) for l in a[0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def lens(listoflists):
  return [len(x) for x in listoflists]
```

now, just call `lens(a[0])` instead of your desired `len(a[0][:])` (you can, if you insist, add that redundant `[:]`, but that's just doing a copy for no purpose whatsoever -- waste not, want not;-).

Answer (score 1):

using the usual "old school" way

```
t=[]
for item in a[0]:
    t.append(len(item))
print t
```

Answer (score 0):

Matthew's answer does not work in Python 3. The following one works in both Python 2 and Python 3

`list(map(len, a[0]))`